# Rails: omniauth-google, how to bypass login?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth

I am implementing a comment functionality to my blog that I created using Ruby on Rails, so that users can write comments on blog posts using their Google account. I added Omniauth so users can login using their Google account to comment on posts made with my blog.

However, what if a user is already signed into Google using Gmail or something? Can I bypass the sign in and have the user be able to write comments on my blog with their Google account?

I am using Rails 3 with the `omniauth-google gem`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. If an user came to your site the first time, he have to authenticate with google to poste something to your site. In the authentication process, the oauth dialog will ask the user, if it is ok, that your app can interact with some google information.

The second time, the user have to click the "login with google" button again, to create a session cookie.

Comment: To be more specific, when the second time the user logs in, can the google-login page be bypassed and the user be logged in automatically?

Comment: if the user is already auto-logged in by google, he/she will be redirected to google and directly will be redirected to your site again..so the user does not have to confirm a second time, everything works in background. if he/she is not logged in, he/she always have to confirm again..